# Creating a jar file to be run on any other machine

Tags: java

I have to create  a jar file wherein i need to add external jar files in the classpath, properties files, in such away as to run it on any other machine.

Comment: Please word your problem as a question and describe which tools you are using (IDE, build management tool, property loading mechanism).

Answer (score 1):

You could either use manifest.mf to define external class path or use script that composes classpath and runs your application.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you to use a build tool such as Maven for these things:

http://maven.apache.org/

[How can I create an executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Regards,

Boskop

Comment: This is my personal favorite answer - I use Maven for every project for some years now and it is really THE Java build tool for me. For creating executable JAR files with dependencies I prefer using the shade plugin, because it's really easy to use and works well.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the jar in almost any IDE. I agree with Michael SchmeiBer, be a bit more specific please.

I use eclipse as my IDE (because you can both use it in windows and Ubuntu Linux) to make a jar (you can define the startup class in the jar).

I use different methods for starting up of different machines.

I use nsis to create a nice windows executable (.exe) You can include your own icon.

In nsis script you actually use the same command you would use in a batch command. 
nsis has some nice features, like search for a java jre.

For Linux and Mac I use a .sh file with this command.